# mod_rewrite check if folder exists, if not redirect as long until a valid subdir is found

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, vhosts

I have the following problem. I have a domain with SEO pages, generated in html each night. This URLs to the pages could look like this:

https://www.mypages.com/seo/florida/miami/somesuburb
but it's possible that "somesuburb" doesn't exist anymore. So it could be, that:

https://www.mypages.com/seo/florida/miami/somesuburb leads to a 404.
also 
https://www.mypages.com/seo/florida/miami could lead to a 404.

So I tried to do this in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (^(.*[\\\/])) /seo/$1 [L,R=301]
```

this works, for example:

https://www.mypages.com/seo/florida/miami/doesntexist
goes to:
https://www.mypages.com/seo/florida/

but if the Dir florida also does not exist, it breaks and gives a 404. I think it is because of the trailing slash.

so my next approach was:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/+$ /seo/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (^(.*[\\\/])) /seo/$1 [L,R]
```

This leads into a loop :(

Could anyone help out here?

Greets!

Comment: Sorry, when writing "liste" i meant "seo"

Answer (score 0):

found a solution:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$/
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /seo/$1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (^(.*[\\\/])) /seo/$1 [L,R]
```

this goes back as long as a dir is valid